# Поиск двузначных чисел в строке

Tags: stl, строки, c++, visual-studio

> Программа должна находить в строках двузначные числа, и считать количество таких строк
>
> примеры строк:
>
> 1. shsjkdfjsfeoi43jlskd
> 2. lkfjsd234kjiel
> 3. jwernmoa43skj3
> 4. jklwen34kje
>
> соответственно таких строки три (1,3,4)

Я начал писать, но оно не работает даже для одной строки, как сделать правильно?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
using namespace std;
string strSample("thisfuckingshitstring45");
cout << "The string:" << endl;
cout << strSample << endl << endl;
int j;
//searching substring
string Num[90] = { "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19",
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29",
    "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39",
    "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49",
    "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59",
    "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69",
    "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78" "79",
    "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89",
    "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99" };
for (j = 0; j < 90; ++j)
{
    size_t charPos = strSample.find(Num[j], 0);
}
    //chekcing search result
    //if (charPos != string::npos)
    //cout << "First instance of "<< Num[j] << " was found at position " << charPos;
    //else cout << "Substring not found." << endl;

    //cout << endl << endl;

    //cout << "loc all substing inc "<< Num[j] << endl;

    size_t SubstingPos = strSample.find(Num[j], 0);

while (SubstingPos != string::npos)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 89; ++j){
    cout << Num[j]<<" found at pos" << SubstingPos << endl;
    size_t nSearchPosition = SubstingPos + 1;
    SubstingPos = strSample.find(Num[j], nSearchPosition);
    }
}

cout << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Если честно, то просто нет желания искать ошибку в реализации *такого* алгоритма. 

IMHO значительно эффективней другой. 

    Перебираем символы строки. Если текущий символ это цифра, то  подсчитываем количество цифр идущих  подряд. Т.е. перебираем дальше,  пока цифра. Смотрим счетчик. Если 2, то нашли, выходим из перебора символов строки, читаем новую строку. Иначе продолжаем перебор в поисках цифры.

Comment: а через подстроки как сделать?

Comment: предлагаю ещё один вариант - проходим циклом по строке. Для каждой позиции проверяем, что текущий символ - цифра, следующий символ - цифра, через один - не цифра или конец строки, а также предыдущий элемент такой же.

Понятно, что проход должен быть на один элемент меньше, чем там символов.

Comment: @Майк, вообще-то все надо делать хорошо, фигово само получится...

--

Но если писать лень, то

    string s;
  
    while (getline(cin, s)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        int pos, n = 0;
        while ((pos = s.find(Num[i], n)) != string::npos) {
          if (check22(s, pos)) {
            cout << s << ": found " << Num[i] << " pos: " << pos << '\n';
            i = 91;
            break;
          }
          n = pos + 2;
        }
      }
    }
    
с `check22()` сами разберетесь?

Answer (score 2):

Если с циклом, то можно так

```
bool lineHasXXnums(const std::string &str)
{
    if (str.length() < 2)
        return false;
    for (auto it = str.cbegin(); it+1 < str.cend(); ++it)
        if (isdigit(*it) && isdigit(*(it+1))) {
            if ((it > str.cbegin() && isdigit(*(it-1))) 
                || (it < str.cend()-2 && isdigit(*(it+2))))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```